# Equal to DQL query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query that should check the start and end date in another entity and compare it against the start and end dates enter to create an instance of an entity, however its not returning anything.

```
  public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Payrollperiod();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $qb = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:PayrollWeek')->createQueryBuilder('p');
            $qb->select('p')
            ->where('p.startDate = :entityStart')
            ->andWhere('p.endDate = :entityEnd')
            ->setParameter('entityStart',$entity->getstartDate())
            ->setParameter('entityEnd',$entity->getendDate())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: Please, post your exception message. Always try to post errors information, it make easier to others help you.

Comment: There should be some query in the question.  The current edit is confusing

Comment: Please *stop* vandalising your question.

Answer (score 2):

How long I've been using Doctrine, I've never seen:

1. In MySQL (and PostgreSQL, SQLite) equal symbol is `=`, not `==`.
2. In DQL you can't use entities' methods like `getStartDate()`, only attributes (in detail you can use only fields and associations defined in entity's mapping).

So:

```
$qb->select('p')                   
    ->where('p.getstartDate()==entity.startDate')
    ->andWhere('p.getendDate()==entity.endDate');
```

Should be:

```
$qb->select('p')
    ->where('p.startDate = entity.startDate')
    ->andWhere('p.getEndDate = entity.endDate')
```

3. What is `entity.*`? You have not declared `entity` Entity in your DQL.

[EDIT] If `entity.*` is another entity and you not define its in Query, then you must parameterize it:

```
$qb->select('p')
    ->where('p.startDate = :entityStart')
    ->andWhere('p.getEndDate = :entityEnd')
    ->setParameter('entityStart', $entity->getStartDate())
    ->setParameter('entityEnd', $entity->getEndDate())
```

Without exception message I cannot tell more about your code. It could be `NonUniqueResultException` because query finds more than 1 result.

Doctrine (and Symfony) have so many exceptions where everything is nice explain - what's crashed, why, where. Sometimes even the name of exception tell us everything - like `UniqueConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: yes it is another entity but an instance of it can only be created if it is in the other entity (table p) with a matching start and end date. I'll try your edit thank you! Is the rest o the code ok?

Comment: I have the above exception

Comment: @leo-ap i was getting the above error message but now it it creating an object whether or not it is in the other entity

Comment: @Zed Please, update your question inserting the code that you posted here and this error message. This error says that you didn't included the DoctrineORM classes correctly into your project